# How to check for multiple conditions in xsl:if in xslt1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a following template in which based on condition match, value should change.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="text()" name="create">
        <xsl:param name="code"/>
        <xsl:param name="boolean"/>

        <xsl:if test="$boolean= 'True'">
            <xsl:value-of select="'Services'"/>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="$code=7">
            <xsl:value-of select="'Accounts'"/>            
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In this, the first condition works. If I pass `boolean = false`, nothing gets assigned. If it is equal to `True`, it's assigning `Services`. But for code, even if I pass `7`, it's not getting assigned. I tried the condition with single quotes also

```
<xsl:if test="$code='7'">
```

I am calling like this

```
       <xsl:variable name="Category">
         <xsl:call-template name="create">
            <xsl:with-param name="code" select="s0:Code"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="boolen" select="'True'"/>
         </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
```

s0:Code is element name which has value 7
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your problem cannot be reproduced using your code.

Comment: I tested your code with `boolean='True'` and `code=7` as parameters and the output is `ServicesAccounts` - as expected.

Comment: Note that `boolen` is not the same as `boolean`.

Answer (score 1):

Your template expects the parameters to be named `code` and `boolean`. You are calling it with parameters named `Occupation` and `Agent`. The template ignores these parameters and operates on the default values of its own parameters (in your example, empty values).

Comment: I think parameter name should not be a problem. It will accept it. I changed it and tried. Then also its not working.

Comment: @user3331421 "not working" is not something I can respond to. Please edit your question and post a **complete** and **reproducible** example, including the XML input - see [mcve].